# Adding entries to list in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, shelve

I have a question about the following:
Let's say I have a datastructure like this

`shelfFile['Test']` which is a dictionary in a shelve file.
I added some values to it using `shelfFile['Test'] = {"January":["Test1","Test2"]}`
Now, when I want to add Test3 using `shelfFile['Test']['January'].append()` it does not work, it returns only the original values "Test1" and "Test2". I have also tried using

```
shelfFile['test'].setdefault('January', []).append('Test3')
```

but this does not work as well, is this due to any mutability of the dictionary/tuple? Maybe someone can recommend some alternative data structure which is more suitable? The "Test" entry is permanent, the month entries are permanent as well although every month a new entry is added. The "Test1", "Test2" can be added or removed at any time.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You tried to use `shelfFile['Test']['January'].append("Test3")` ? Because it works for me...

Answer (score 2):

According to [`shelve` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html),

> Because of Python semantics, a shelf cannot know when a mutable
>   persistent-dictionary entry is modified. **By default modified objects
>   are written only when assigned to the shelf** (see [Example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve-example)). If the
>   optional writeback parameter is set to True, all entries accessed are
>   also cached in memory, and written back on sync() and close(); this
>   can make it handier to mutate mutable entries in the persistent
>   dictionary, but, if many entries are accessed, it can consume vast
>   amounts of memory for the cache, and it can make the close operation
>   very slow since all accessed entries are written back (there is no way
>   to determine which accessed entries are mutable, nor which ones were
>   actually mutated).

```
d = shelfFile['Test']         # extract a copy
d['January'].append('Test3')  # mutate
shelfFile['Test'] = d         # stores the copy right back, to persist it
```